# Searching for service area businesses using Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-my-business-api

I'm trying to understand a problem that I'm having at the moment,
I created a Google map on my web app so my users can search for their businesses,
It appears that they can search and find only businesses with a precise location,
Service area businesses cannot be found using my map,
This is the link to my map on my server: [My Map](https://app.brainer.io/map_test.html)

Then I found a Google link that I can find also the service area businesses,
This is the link to the Google Map: [Google Map](https://google-developers.appspot.com/my-business/content/tools/placeid-lookup)

I compared (vimdiff) the source codes of the two links and they are the same,
So my question is why I can't see service area businesses on my map ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Service Area Businesses are not available for Places API users and this is Google's decision. There was a feature request to enable SABs in Places API, but unfortunately Google rejected it.

You can read more here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828187

I copy the last answer from Google:

> The Places API team has reviewed this feature request and decided against including Service Area Businesses results in API responses.
>
> Places API mission is to enable developers to help users find relevant places to visit. Since Service Area Businesses are not places users can visit, and therefore do not belong in the Places API.
>
> The ability to find Service Area Businesses have been removed from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder to be consistent with the funtionality generally available in the Places API. Google My Business users can still find Place IDs for their Service Area Businesses using a dedicated PlaceID Lookup Tool at https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/faq#associate_locations_using_placeid_1
>
> We do acknowledge there is demand for this feature and will look into accommodating it in the future. To this end, we would appreciate if you shared specific use cases and business needs that this feature would enable for you.

Referring to the Google My Business find place ID page, they use their own Cloud project where this feature is available, but no way for Google Maps API users to get this.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt!